# DispatcherServler does not work

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am trying to create a simple Spring project. Once I run the project it shows the content of index.jsp but when I enter hello.jsp it shows its content but when I enter hello.htm it shows "The requested resource is not available." error message.

**springapp-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean name="/hello.htm" class="springapp.web.HelloController"/>
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>
            index.jsp
        </welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

[image]

I changed the address of the class of bean but it did not show any error.

```
<bean name="/hello.htm" class="springapp.web.HelloController1"/>
```

After adding viewResolver the problem was solved but I have another issue that is posted as a separate question. If you have an issue with the addressing please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686198/cannot-find-org-springframework-util-classutils-getmethod-and-could-not-initiali).

Comment: Is your controller class invoked with hello.htm? Can you confirm?

Comment: @VimalBera no thats why I am suspecting dispatcherservlet. When I append hello.htm to the address it shows "description The requested resource is not available."

Comment: Generally requested resource not found error comes when there is a problem in URL mapping. When the requested URL does not match to any of the URL patterns, it throws this exception. Provide stacktrace when server started.

Comment: Is HelloController getting constructed?

Comment: @VimalBera it just shows the details of the computer,Tomcat configuration and Feb 23, 2015 5:30:04 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:Spring' did not find a matching property.
Feb 23, 2015 5:30:04 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Spring2' did not find a matching property.

Comment: @Stefan It looks like it does not as I added a constructor to it and it never output anything on console.

Comment: you have not defined view resolver bean in your servlet-context file

Comment: @VasudevPathak  how to define that? I thought as I did not define that I are going to be given a default one by Spring that simply forwards to a URL matching the name of the view specified.

Comment: try to change <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern> to <url-pattern>/*.htm</url-pattern>

Comment: @VasudevPathak same result!

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/   find solution here.

Comment: still if you are not able to find solution then just update your question with controller and stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code in your springapp-servlet.xml

```
 <bean name="/hello.htm" class="springapp.web.HelloController1"/>


<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: After this, I had an issue with Listener to solve that I did following: selected Project properties > Deployment Assembly > Add > Java Build Path > Maven Dependency > Finish