# Cannot find org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getMethod and could not initialize DefaultConversionService

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Once I run my application it shows following error in the console. I studied this question but its [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851236/spring-mvc-http-status-500-servlet-init-for-servlet-logindispacher-threw-e) was not helpful.

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getMethod(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.<clinit>(GenericConversionService.java:81)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.<init>(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:41)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.<init>(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:41)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.<init>(AbstractEnvironment.java:112)
    at org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.<init>(StandardEnvironment.java:54)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.<init>(StandardServletEnvironment.java:44)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.createEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.getEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5550)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Feb 24, 2015 10:20:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [springapp] in web application [/Spring2] threw load() exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getMethod(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.<clinit>(GenericConversionService.java:81)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.<init>(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:41)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.<init>(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:41)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.<init>(AbstractEnvironment.java:112)
    at org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.<init>(StandardEnvironment.java:54)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.<init>(StandardServletEnvironment.java:44)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.createEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.getEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5550)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Although, it shows the first page of the application, when I enter an address it shows following error rather than content of the selected page.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet springapp threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService
    org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.<init>(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:41)
    org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.<init>(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:41)
    org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.<init>(AbstractEnvironment.java:112)
    org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.<init>(StandardEnvironment.java:54)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.<init>(StandardServletEnvironment.java:44)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.createEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.getEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I suppose the problem is related to my dependencies but do not know how to solve it.

**pom.xml**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Spring2</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spring2</name>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>Spring</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

**pom.xml2**

I updated my maven dependencies as following to no avail

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I expected the problem was with the dependencies. I could solve the issue by updating my pom.xml and cleaning the project.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Spring2</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spring2</name>


    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```